# Tracking facebooklike button on my website

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I have a video in my site but before playing the video, visitor must like my facebook page. The problem that when he come back to the website he could not see the video again because the like button in inactive.
I'm using javascript.
Thank you for your understanding and I'm waiting for your help

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays == null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString());
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if(c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if(c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function lecture_vid() {
    var cc = '<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/IAsjjSkaWVc?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    $("#vid_real").html(cc);
}
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    setCookie('edgeTV', '1', 350);
    faceclick();
});

function faceclick() {
    lecture_vid();
    $('#confirme_jaime').empty().hide();
}
```

Comment: So..? what have you tried? show us some code. what do you want us to do?

Comment: what i want is simple: when the vistor likes my page, he can see the video anytime he wants

Comment: Why would you force someone to like something they haven't seen?

Comment: i don't want to force anyone... but it's my own video if you want to see it you will have to like my page.. In the end, it's your choice.

Comment: Why the hell don't you indent your code?!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a user liked your page when being outside of Facebook (meaning not in a canvas/page tab app), then you have to have the user connect to your app, and get permission to read his likes.

This might be a little over the top for what you want to achieve (I wouldn’t connect to any app just to see a video).

So your only other option would be to safe the info that the user has clicked the like button on your page into some kind of database.

But that still does not give you any info to work with for users who have already liked your page before – those would have to unlike your page and like it again. Bad user experience for them, and bad for your page, because Facebook might take that unliking/liking, especially if it happens multiple times for one user, into consideration when determining you page’s ranking …